# Should I use `git rebase` with `git push --force-with-lease` frequently?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-push

I'll checkout to a feature branch, and so do my teammates.

When they merge their feature branch to master. I have to handle conflicts.

I hate the commits like `Merge branch 'master' into feature/[branchName]` and I prefer the history modified by `rebase` rather than `merge`.
So I'll usually do:

```
git rebase master
git push origin feature/[branchName] --force-with-lease
```

But I am wondering if it is a correct way, since I use `git push --force-with-lease` frequently.

Comment: *I hate the commits like Merge branch 'master' into feature/[branchName]* how do you keep track of when merges happened and where these came from? If you want to use git like this then that seems fine (it's up to you) but this method seems to make your traceabillity much reduced simply because of a bit of OCD

Comment: What I'm talking about is dealing the conflicts between my current branch and master. I'll keep `Merge branch feature/[branchName] into 'master' `, but not `Merge branch 'master' into feature/[branchName]` . I'll do `merge` when I'm on `master` and there's a feature is done.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I use `git rebase` with `git push --force-with-lease` frequently?

You should use the workflow that is agreed between you and your teammates. If you agree that you will merge `master` into any `feature` and then merge the `feature` into `master`, then all **should** do that because you decided as a team to follow this workflow.

If you have not discussed this and nobody has any strong opinions on the matter, then:

1. Try to build a workflow so that your team has some coherency with your git.
2. (and if 1. yields little progress) Do what's more comfortable to you.

In your case specifically, your methodology of rebasing a feature branch on top of master is not bad and is used by many other people. I prefer to do like that, so that master stays *clean*.

Comment: No worries, these things are hard to negotiate